# no package called ‘sjlabelled’

Tags: r, sjplot

I'm trying to use `sjt.lmer` to make a table of my lmer regression results, however, when I tried to library package `sjPlot`, this error displayed:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sjPlot’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
  there is no package called ‘sjlabelled’
```

I've already installed package `sjlabelled`, `sjmisc`, `sjPlot` but still doesn't work. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you do `library(sjPlot)`? Are you certain that `install.packages("sjPlot")` completed successfully?

Comment: Did you try load `library(sjlabelled)` and `library(sjmisc)` individually to see where the problem could lie at? If you can narrow down which dependency(ies) are causing the error, you can try reinstalling it.